# Proving that $A \vee (\neg A \wedge B) \equiv A \vee B$

Tags: logic, arithmetic, boolean-algebra

I'm reading a book at the moment about logic gates and Boolean simplification. There is a part which I can't seem to follow.

I can easily work out that $A \vee (\neg A \wedge B) \equiv A \vee B$ using a truth table as it's easy to see.

However, I can't seem to turn $A \vee (\neg A \wedge B)$ into $A \vee B$ using steps such as distributive / absorption etc.

Can someone talk me through the steps that you would take to simplify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

$\qquad A \lor (B \land C) \equiv (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$;

you can "multiply out". Add in

$\qquad (A \lor \lnot A) \land B \equiv B$

and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I clearly need a little more work as I'm not sure about 'multiplying out' but it at least points me in the right direction.

Comment: @user1480135 It follows from distributivity: $(A \lor B) \land (A \lor C) \equiv (A \land A) \lor (A \land C) \lor (A \land B) \lor (B \land C)$ which simplifies to $A \lor (B\land C)$ using absorption. And $A \land A \equiv A$, whatever the name of that is. :)

Comment: @Raphael. It's sometimes called "idempotent".

Comment: The "multiplying out" property *is* just one of the two distributive laws, which is fair game game according to the question. So what's the need to prove it?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The OP being "not sure about" it?

Comment: Then reassure them.

Answer (score 6):

I'll write your expression as $A\lor(\neg A\land B)$. Then
$$\begin{align}
A\lor B &= A\lor((A\lor\neg A)\land B) &\text{identity}\\
 &=A\lor (A\land B)\lor(\neg A\land B) &\text{distributive}\\
 &=(A\lor (A\land B))\lor(\neg A\land B)\\
 &= A\lor(\neg A\land B) &\text{absorption}
\end{align}$$

Comment: If we wanted to be really picky, we'd note the use of associativity in steps 2 and 3.

Comment: @Raphael. Heh. Yes, I suppose so.

Comment: Isn't it easier (more natural) to apply distributivily directly to $A \lor(\lnot A\land B)$ ?

Comment: @HendrikJan. Yup, that would work too. Wonder why I didn't think of that first?

Comment: Well I do not blame you: I once wrote a five line solution for what was actually an axiom of the logic.

Answer (score 3):

$$a \lor (\neg a \land b) \equiv (\underbrace{a \lor \neg a}_{\equiv \text{True}}) \land (a \lor b) \equiv \text{True} \land (a \lor b) \equiv a \lor b$$

Comment: That's essentially my answer.

Answer (score -1):

absorption rule: (if P then Q) iff (if P then (P and Q))
identity: (if P then Q) iff ((not P) or Q)
so: (A or B) iff (if(not A) then B) (by identity)
hence: (A or B) iff (if(not A) then ((not A) and B)) (by absorption)
hence: (A or B) iff (A or ((not A) and B)) (by identity)

Basically, (A or B) iff (A or ((not A) and B)) is the absorption rule

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction. Thank you.